# Change Start of Named Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a single namedRange that (for example) incorrectly starts in Row 5 of Column 1 when it should start in Row 2 (under a header row).

**NOTE:** *In reality I don't know where it 'starts' only that it is somewhere BELOW where it should be.*

I am trying to move the namedRange using like this:

```
    Set SecondCellInFirstColumnOfNamedRange = Range(rngNames(irng)).Columns(1).Cells(2)
    Set LastCellInFirstColumnOfNamedRange = Range(rngNames(irng)).Columns(1).Cells(RowNumberOfLastCell)
    Range(SecondCellInFirstColumnOfNamedRange, LastCellInFirstColumnOfNamedRange).Name = rngNames(irng)
```

But it just keeps pushing the named range down the page.

What I have been trying to do is this:

- find the column index of the first cell
- specify the 2nd cell in the column as the start of the namedRange
- specify the last used cell in the column as the end of the namedRange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your named range already ends at the right row, a quick fix would be:

```
With Range(rngNames(irng))
    .Offset(-3).Resize(.Rows.Count + 3).Name = rngNames(irng)
End With
```

The principle is to name a range that starts 3 rows above and is 3 rows "longer".

**Edit**: as per your updated question:

```
With Range(rngNames(irng))
    .Worksheet.Range(.Columns(1).EntireColumn.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge)).Name = rngNames(irng)
End With
```

Note that you shouldn't call Range without it being qualified by its parent, e.g. you should use `MyWorksheet.Range(...)`. This allows you to work free of whatever is active.

Comment: Thanks for this - I now realize that my "Minimal" example was too simple.  I have other named ranges which have also shifted but for which I do NOT know what the offset should be.  I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: OMG - you don't know how much time you saved me, thanks!